# wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am updating my app to rails 4 i am using

```
<%= form_for @application do |f|%>
<%end-%>
```

for the form tag but it always gives me

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [form\_for wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) since upgrade to rails 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523252/form-for-wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for-2-since-upgrade-to-rails-3-1)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this does not work for me :( .
I have used now 

     <%= form_for @application,:as => 'application' do |f|%>
but same error

Comment: @user2752370 Are you certain this is where the error message is coming from? If so, why? Please include traces when reporting errors. Are you showing the complete source?

Comment: @Dave . I will take care for that. actually i was updating may app and removed the client side validation gem. and all that validations . preiviously this forn was wroking .

Comment: can you show us how do you set @application in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, it was due to client_side_validation gem. This gem is conflicting with form_for in rails 4

Comment: I do not use client_side_validations and am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Rails 4 then Client Side validation is outdated. You can check here

http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations?view=comments

and also if you go to the github page

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

you can see that it says its no longer maintained.

Alternatively you can try using the CSV gem from this branch, by replacing the CSV line in your Gemfile by this

```
gem 'client_side_validations', github: "bcardarella/client_side_validations", :branch => "4-0-beta"
```

Not sure even if this will work though. Since its outdated.

Or you can check this gem out,

https://github.com/kalkov/rails4_client_side_validations

Its just a modified version of Client Side Validations

And for the whitespace stuff. lol. It can be used both at the beginning or at the end of the  <% end %> tag. Its only for earlier version of Rails since in Rails 3 its no longer necessary.If an erb tag has no output it will automatically be stripped away so there’s no unnecessary whitespace where the erb tags were.

Comment: I do not use client_side_validations and am still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be here

```
<%end-%>
```

as it should be

```
<%end%> #no hyphen after the 'd'
```

However, I'm not sure why it would throw that error if that were the case.  Is there anything between `form_for` and `end`?

Comment: The hyphen means to strip out whitespace. Even if it wasn't, that wouldn't cause that issue; it would be a Ruby syntax error.

Comment: ah i thought that went before the 'end' like `<%-end%>` - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To install "Client side validations" with simple_form successfully, you should check for latest versions direct from Github with latest branch.

The released gems don't work with Rails >= 4.0

```
gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

Make sure your gem file does not use these versions

```
client-side Validation 3.2.5
client_side_validations-simple_form 2.1.0
```

These versions does not support rails 4.2.0

For more detail please check this link,
https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form/issues/41